# How to completly remove postgresql from Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql
sudo apt-get autoremove postgresql
```

and

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
```

But after this `dpkg -l | grep postgres` gives me that:

```
pi  postgresql-9.1                            9.1.11-0ubuntu0.13.04                    amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.1 server
pi  postgresql-client-9.1                     9.1.11-0ubuntu0.13.04                    amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.1
ii  postgresql-client-common                  140                                      all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                         140                                      all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib                        9.1+140                                  all          additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)
ii  postgresql-contrib-9.1                    9.1.11-0ubuntu0.13.04                    amd64        additional facilities for PostgreSQL
ii  postgresql-doc-9.1                        9.1.11-0ubuntu0.13.04                    all          documentation for the PostgreSQL database management system
```

And if I try to start `psql`:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So, as I can see, postgresql is installed.

Comment: I've tried `sudo apt-get --purge remove ` all packages shown by `dpkg -l | grep postgres` and `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
`. And it worked for me.

Comment: It works, but it is unneeded. Every package doing something with postgresql depends on postgresql-common, thus it is enough if you purge this package out by the apt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove PostgreSQL completely by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'postgresql-*'
sudo apt-get autoremove 'postgresql-*'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get --purge remove postgresql-common
```

With dpkg --info `<packagename>` you can see, which is required by this current package. In most cases, there is a simple package, which is needed by all. This can be removed with apt.

Answer (score 1):

`psql` is from `postgresql-client` package. So - remove it using the full name of the package:

```
apt-get remove postgresql-client-9.1
```

Comment: It removes only the package files, but doesn't remove the configuration, etc. The packages remain in the system package catalog, although in an "r" (=removed) state, instead of "i" (=installed).

Comment: if there is need to remove configuration files - it's enought to use dpkg -P package to remove it.